# Could Git Bash run daemon process periodically?

Tags: bash, windows-server, daemon

I have this `myscript.sh` act as a performance monitor in Windows Server. To do so, I'm trying my best here to avoid using WSL and using Git Bash to run the script but the problem is the script just execute it once after I put the command to run it. Is there any command that I can use to run it in daemon or maybe let the script run periodically based on our time interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GUI built into Windows you can use to periodically run a script. You can easily choose a few common time intervals like 5, 10, and 15 minutes, and daily, weekly, and monthly. I admit, these intervals seem too great, you probably want to run your script every few seconds if I understand correctly.

Can Task Scheduler be of help?

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Choose "Create Basic Task" in
   the right side pane of the window
3. Name and describe your task. Click next as you progress through the wizard.
4. Choose a trigger that determines when your task will start. For your case, you might select "when a specific event is logged".
5. For the "action", select "start a program" and click "browse" to point Task Scheduler to your `myscript.sh`
6. Now you can edit your task by checking the box "Open the Properties dialog for this when I click Finish". After clicking finish you may also double click the task at any time to edit it.

I admit, I know very little on whether or not you can easily cause events that Windows can see. The interface for choosing events is quite technical. Maybe it's worth the effort, though. You wrote

> based on our time interval

which got me thinking, maybe you could easily change the interval of your monitoring script this way (without opening task scheduler ever again). Type your new value into some other script that causes *events*, therefore starting the monitoring script at any precise interval you want.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I never thought sh script could be execute directly in task scheduler since I thought it would need some environment to do so.